# On the informal interpretation of the first moment method.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I am following Terrence Tao notes on concentration inequalities that can be found [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/#zero).

Define $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ where $X_i, 1 \le i \le n$ are random variables. From the famous Markov inequality we have

$$P( |S_n| \geq \lambda ) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf E} |X_i|.$$

Tao states that one can informally view this as "the assertion that ${S_n}$ typically has size ${S_n = O( \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| )}.$" What is the reason for this?

I realize that if $\lambda > \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$ then

$$P( |S_n| \geq \lambda ) < \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|} \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf E} |X_i|.$$

So the probability that $|S_n| \ge \lambda$ is smaller than a random variable that has expected value equal to one half. Is this the reason or something else?

Comment: Perhaps this explanation is good enough for you: think of a constant random variable Y such that the inequality above holds with Y in place of $|S_n|$.. You can easily check that the constant value has to be at most equal to $\sum E|X_i|$. Conversely if a constant random variable does not exceed  $\sum E|X_i|$  then  the inequality holds.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have a doubt; "The constant value has to be at most equal to $\sum E |X_i|$? " Why is this?

Comment: Just take a $\lambda $ equal to the constant value of $|S_n|$. Left side of eh inequality is 1 so we get   $1 \leq \frac 1 {\lambda} \sum E|X_i|$ which means the constant value $\lambda$ is less then or equal to $\sum E|X_i|$